# Нахождение центра окружности(описанной) по кординатам

Tags: ассемблер, геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

У меня такой вопрос. Я получаю от пользователя кординаты 3-ёх точек (x,y). Эти три точки являются вершинами треугольника. Моя задача заключается в том , что я должен найти центр описанной окружности, т.е кординаты центра. У кого есть идеи как это можно сделать.

Comment: пересечение перпендикуляров к двум сторонам треугольника, проведенных через середины этих сторон (при чем здесь ассемблер?)

Answer (score 2):

Центр описанной окружности определяется через формулы

```
    | x_a^2 + y_a^2   y_a   1 |
x = | x_b^2 + y_b^2   y_b   1 | * 1/d
    | x_c^2 + y_c^2   y_c   1 |

    | x_a^2 + y_a^2   x_a   1 |
y = | x_b^2 + y_b^2   x_b   1 | * -1/d
    | x_c^2 + y_c^2   x_c   1 |
```

где `(x_a, y_a)`, `(x_b, y_b)`, `(x_c, y_c)` - координаты вершин треугольника, а знаменатель `d` определяется как

```
    | x_a   y_a   1 |
d = | x_b   y_b   1 | * 2
    | x_c   y_c   1 |
```

А ещё есть википедия с более богатым набором формул. Например, [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C#.D0.94.D0.BB.D1.8F_.D1.82.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.83.D0.B3.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0).